# Problem using ObjectID in MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell, objectid

I am learning to use MongoDB, I have created a cluster in the cloud at cloud.mongodb.com, and I connect to it with MongoDb Compass vs 1.22.1.
I am trying to learn some basic commands, and I am trying to select items from my collection using the find() command to filter by id.

I have tried what I have seen being referenced everywhere, like:

```
db.recipes.find({_id: ObjectID("5e877cba20a4f574c0aa56da")});
```

or

```
db.recipes.find({'_id': ObjectID("5e877cba20a4f574c0aa56da")});
```

And I always get the output:

```
ReferenceError: ObjectID is not defined
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:5:10
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:7:3
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:134:20)
    at Object.runInContext (vm.js:297:6)
    at ElectronInterpreterEnvironment.sloppyEval (C:\Users\lfili\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompass\app-1.22.1\resources\app.asar\node_modules\@mongodb-js\compass-shell\lib\index.js:140827:28)
    at Interpreter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lfili\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompass\app-1.22.1\resources\app.asar\node_modules\@mongodb-js\compass-shell\lib\index.js:210735:41)
    at step (C:\Users\lfili\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompass\app-1.22.1\resources\app.asar\node_modules\@mongodb-js\compass-shell\lib\index.js:210685:19)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\lfili\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompass\app-1.22.1\resources\app.asar\node_modules\@mongodb-js\compass-shell\lib\index.js:210615:14)
    at C:\Users\lfili\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompass\app-1.22.1\resources\app.asar\node_modules\@mongodb-js\compass-shell\lib\index.js:210587:67
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

If I dont use ObjectID, like:

```
db.recipes.find({'_id':"5e877cba20a4f574c0aa56da"});
```

I get no error but there is no output because I guess the _id is not "5e877cba20a4f574c0aa56da" but ObjectID("5e877cba20a4f574c0aa56da").

I don't know why can't use the ObjectID in the Compass MongoSH, any help would be welcome.
Thank you

Comment: It is `ObjectId` _not_ `ObjectID`.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried and it worked, it is strange because the output in >_MongoSH is in the format _id: ObjectID("5e877cba20a4f574c0aa56da"), so I just copied it from there.

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions you have to use

```
db.recipes.find({_id: ObjectId("5e877cba20a4f574c0aa56da")});
```

If you're using an older version before 1.10.x you can use:

```
db.recipes.find({"_id":{"$oid":"5e877cba20a4f574c0aa56da"}});
```

Comment: Thank you! I was using the format for the newer version, the problem as prasad_ pointed out was that I was using ObjectID instead of ObjectId, because I have copied it from the output in the console and it outputs as ObjectID instead of ObjectId.